# Removing root site from navigation menu

Tags: navigation

I am trying to show my site hierarchy on the navigation menu. To hide the root site from menu,
in sharepoint designer iam removing the

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" Id="topNavigationDelegate">
    <Template_Controls>
```

tags. But then menu is completely disappearing. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I believe there is Property in that control called `ShowRootNode` or something similar. Set that to false and it should solve it.

Comment: I already set ShowRootNode to false. But to take it affect, delegate tags must be removed.I am removing it, but the navigation menu is completely disappearing.